# Testing with HTF

Tags: testing, haskell, htf

There's an incredible lack of decent documentation on HTF. All I could find was a [Tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTF/0.7.1.0/doc/html/Test-Framework-Tutorial.html) which doesn't provide any of the following really important information:

1. How do I create a test suite that automatically executes all tests from packages?
2. What exactly are those "Black box tests" of HTF and how do I create them?
3. What are the actual standards of setting up a test suite based on HTF (source root, packages and modules structure, cabal)?

Comment: A nice canonical example package would be good. I looked through a bunch of Haskell projects on Github (maybe not the best source, but still...) to see how they did tests, and *everybody* did it at least a little differently.

Comment: I would contact the author of the package.

Comment: @jberryman I actually did and pointed him to this question. I guess we'll have to wait.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply, but I've seen this thread here only lately. The new release 0.9.0.0 of HTF now comes with quite a lot of documentation. Also, I moved development to https://github.com/skogsbaer/HTF/. I hope this will make it easier for people to use HTF and to ask questions about HTF. Feel free to do so!

Comment: @stefanwehr Thanks! Please post your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov That's what I've done now, I just wanted to wait until hackage generated the API documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new release 0.9.0.0 of HTF (see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTF-0.9.0.0 and https://github.com/skogsbaer/HTF/) hopefully answers all your questions. I'll summarize:

- Answer to question 1: See the tutorial, http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTF/0.9.0.0/doc/html/Test-Framework-Tutorial.html. It explains how to setup a main module that executes all tests defined in your package, see the section "Test definitions in multiple modules"
- Answer to question 2: The documentation of the BlackBoxTest module http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTF/0.9.0.0/doc/html/Test-Framework-BlackBoxTest.html now explains in detail what a black box test is and how to use it.
- Answer to question 3: The HTF repository at https://github.com/skogsbaer/HTF/ now contains a `sample` directory with a complete sample project.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan! And btw a great project!