# Analog of Ruby Bundler Gemfile/Gemfile.lock for Haskell Cabal

Tags: haskell, dependency-management, cabal, cabal-install

Does there exist an analog of Ruby [Bundler](http://bundler.io)'s [Gemfile](http://bundler.io/v1.6/man/gemfile.5.html) and [`bundle install`](http://bundler.io/v1.6/bundle_install.html), [`bundle exec`](http://bundler.io/v1.6/bundle_exec.html) commands for Haskell Cabal?

Here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662806/is-there-any-haskell-land-equivalent-to-the-ruby-lands-bundler-et-al-and-if-n), but it seems to be mostly about project scaffolding.

Answer (score 1):

Cabal v1.20 announced a new feature called "freeze" to make builds more reproducible and reduce proverbial "cabal hell".

Source: http://blog.johantibell.com/2014/04/announcing-cabal-120.html

This offers almost the same functionality as bundle install.